# sudo apt-get install gcc-9-base libgcc-9-dev libc6-dev

Tags: linux, debian

I can't install anything because this issues

when I try --fix-broken install

the terminal shows :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 clang-6.0 : Depends: libgcc-8-dev but it is not installed
 clang-7 : Depends: libgcc-8-dev but it is not installed
 gcc-8 : Depends: libgcc-8-dev (= 8.3.0-6) but it is not installed
 libobjc-8-dev : Depends: libgcc-8-dev (= 8.3.0-6) but it is not installed
 libstdc++-8-dev : Depends: libgcc-8-dev (= 8.3.0-6) but it is not installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

pls help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this error because you are holding some unmet dependencies.
Open terminal window and run the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You can then go ahead and install you package by running the command `sudo apt-get install gcc`